# Deriving the age of the universe

Tags: cosmology, time, space-expansion, universe, big-bang

I am trying to work out the solution to exercise 8.4 from An Introduction to Modern Cosmology by Andrew Liddle. I could derive the Friedmann equation as below,

$$\dot{a}^2 = H_0^2 \left[\Omega_0a^{-1} + (1 - \Omega_0)a^2\right]$$

How to I derive either of the equation below from the equation above?

$$H_0t_0 = \frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\Omega_0}}\ln\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\Omega_0}}{\sqrt{\Omega_0}}\right]$$
or
$$H_0t_0 = \frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\Omega_0}}\sinh^{-1}\left[\sqrt{\frac{1-\Omega_0}{\Omega_0}}\right]$$

Comment: Have you tried the usual: square root, separation of variables, and integration by either substituting cleverly or asking wolframalpha/Gradsteyn&Ryzhik?

Comment: Start by putting the expansion parameter $a(t)$ on on side of the equation, and all the t's on the other. To do this, start with recalling $\dot{a}^2 = (da/dt)^2$, take the square root, and simplify to, $da/[\Omega_0a^{-1} + (1-\Omega_0)a^2]^{1/2} = H_0dt$. Now, integrate and be clever about your u-substitution, or find your favorite books of integrals... If you are wondering about the bounds, integrate $\int_0^{t_0}dt H_0$ and for $a$, I would guess to integrate from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried doing the integration. The resulting integral looks something like the below,

$$H_0t_0 = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\Omega_0a^{-1}+(1-\Omega_0)a^2}}da$$

I tried using a few substitutions and none of them simplified the integral further. Any thoughts on an appropriate integral?

Comment: I have taken the limits on a to be 0 assuming the at the big bang, the universe was small and $$a_0 = 1$$ for the present epoch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While doing these types of calculations always use integral calculator site (https://www.integral-calculator.com/)

There’s a trick that always works while taking these kind of integrals.

1. Write down the Friedman equation in terms of scale factor
2. If there are 2 parameters, you need to eliminate on of the parameters by taking outside the square root. In this case the denominator becomes

$$\sqrt{1-\Omega_0}\sqrt{\frac{\Omega_0}{1-\Omega_0}a^{-1}+a^{2}}$$

3. set $k=\sqrt{\frac{\Omega_0}{1-\Omega_0}}$ (just naming this as a constant)
4. In the integral calculator, type the integral as
   $$\int \frac{da}{\sqrt{ka^{-1}+a^2}}$$

The answer should be $$\frac{2\ln(\sqrt{a^3+k}+a^{3/2})}{3}+C$$

Now we have

$$H_0t_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\Omega_0}}[\frac{2\ln(\sqrt{1+k}+1^{3/2})}{3} - \frac{2\ln(\sqrt{k})}{3}] $$

I guess you can do the rest.